# H_3 of SL(n,Z) and SL(n,F_p)

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, arithmetic-groups

Can anyone tell me what $H_3(SL_n(\mathbb{Z});\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_3(SL_n(\mathbb{F}_p);\mathbb{Z})$ are?  It is easy to find references for $H_1$ and $H_2$, but it turns out that I need $H_3$ as well.  All I care about are the stable values.

Comment: I don't know the F_p case. If memory serves, H_3(SL_n(Z)) = Z/24 for n large. I left this as a comment rather than answer both because I am missing the F_p case and because I don't have a reference handy. (I can dig for one if needed.)

Comment: I happen to remember that H_3(SL_2(3)) = Z/24, in case that helps. This number 24 shows up a lot.

Comment: Quickest reference is probably 4.1.20 in Weibel's K-book (page 299 there): for integers it gives what @Theo says, for a finite field with $q$ elements --- $\mathbb Z/(q^2-1)\mathbb Z$ (stabilization is from $n=3$ on)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I couldn't find this at the location you suggested, although I don't have the published version available. There is an Exercise 1.20 in Chapter IV on page 16 of http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook.html, which I think would be page 299 of the book. Probably you mean that these answers can be extracted from Chaper IV Corollary 1.20? Do you mind providing more instruction? I have left a CW answer you could edit, or you could leave a complete answer on your own.

Comment: @Theo Right, I had this in mind. It requires quite a lot of previous material though - calculation of $K_2(\mathbb Z)$ (IV.5.2.2), $K_3(\mathbb Z)$ (VI.10) and the multiplication $\{-1,\_,\_\}$ (1.19) and (1.20) as well as $K$-theory of finite fields (1.13)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, the stable ($n\geq 3$) values of $H_3(SL_n;\mathbb Z)$ are

- $H_3(SL_\infty(\mathbb Z);\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z/24$
- $H_3(SL_\infty(\mathbb F_q);\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z/(q^2-1)$

and can be found in Weibel's [The $K$-book](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook.html).

Namely, one has 
$$
K_2(R)\xrightarrow{[-1]}K_3(R)\to H_3(E(R))\to0
$$
for any ring (Corollary IV.1.20 there), with $K_2(R)=H_2(E(R);\mathbb Z)$ and $K_3(R)=H_3(St(R);\mathbb Z)$, where $E(R)\subseteq GL(R)$ is the subgroup generated by elementary matrices and $St(R)\twoheadrightarrow E(R)$ is its universal central extension.

For most decent rings, including integers and fields, $E_n=SL_n$; for $R$ the integers, $K_2(\mathbb Z)=H_2(SL_n(\mathbb Z))=\mathbb Z/2$ (Milnor), $K_3(\mathbb Z)=H_3(St_n(\mathbb Z))=\mathbb Z/48$ ([Lee & Szczarba 1976](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1971055)), and the map $[-1]$ is nonzero. For $R=\mathbb F_q$, $K_2$ is zero and $K_3$ is $\mathbb Z/(q^2-1)$ (Quillen).